# Findbugs and PMD plugins on Gradle

Tags: gradle, findbugs, pmd

is it possible to generate only one html file for all modules (one for Findbugs and another for PMD), so I could upload somewhere those two html file for review?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Gradle itself supports combining these reports; however, you should be able to do it manually with some XSLT -- http://www.sw-engineering-candies.com/blog-1/howtotransformtheresultsfromfindbugscheckstyleandpmdintoasinglehtmlreportwithxslt20andjava